# Adding new field with complex conditions in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my Auction application, I have 3 primary tables, Auctions, Bids, and User. I'm trying to build a MongoDB query where I can get the highest bid of each user on each auction (if they placed a bid), also I want to have a column that says the status of the user on that particular auction. I'm able to get all columns except the status column which is kinda complicated.

Logic for status column

1. If the auction has not ended:

   1. If the user is the highest bidder then "You are the highest bidder".
   2. If the user is not the highest bidder then "You have been outbid".
2. If the auction has ended:

   1. If the user is the highest bidder then "You won the auction".
   2. If the user is not the highest bidder then "You lost the auction".

In my Auction application, I have 3 main tables, Auction, Bids and Users. Table structure shown below

Users

| userID | fullName | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | xxxx | bidder |
| User2 | xxxx | bidder |
| User3 | xxxx | bidder |

Auctions

| auctionID | startDate | endDate | startingPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2023-09-20T12:37:00Z | 2023-09-21T12:37:00Z | 100 |
| 10002 | 2023-09-22T12:37:00Z | 2023-09-22T12:37:00Z | 2000 |
| 10003 | 2023-09-22T12:37:00Z | 2023-09-25T12:37:00Z | 800 |
| 10004 | 2023-09-22T12:37:00Z | 2023-09-26T12:37:00Z | 3000 |

Bids

| bidID | auctionID | bidderID | bidAmount | bidDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10001 | User1 | 120 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 102 | 10001 | User2 | 140 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 103 | 10001 | User1 | 160 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 104 | 10001 | User2 | 200 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 105 | 10001 | User1 | 240 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 106 | 10002 | User3 | 2200 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 107 | 10002 | User2 | 2400 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 108 | 10002 | User1 | 2800 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 109 | 10002 | User2 | 3200 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 110 | 10002 | User3 | 3400 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 111 | 10003 | User1 | 900 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 112 | 10003 | User2 | 1200 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 113 | 10003 | User3 | 1600 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |
| 114 | 10003 | User2 | 1800 | 2023-09-20T13:33:44Z |

Expected Result

| userID | auctionID | maxBidAmount | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1001 | 240 | You won the auction |
| User1 | 1002 | 2800 | You lost the auction |
| User1 | 1003 | 900 | You have been outbid |
| User2 | 1001 | 200 | You lost the auction |
| User2 | 1002 | 3200 | You lost the auction |
| User2 | 1003 | 1800 | You are the highest bidder |
| User3 | 1002 | 3400 | You won the auction |
| User3 | 1003 | 1600 | You have been outbid |

Here is my mongodb query which gives wrong result in status column

```
this.bidModel.aggregate([
            {
                $sort: {
                    auction: 1, 
                    bidAmount: -1 
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        bidder: "$bidder",
                        auction: "$auction"
                    },
                    highestBid: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
                }
            },
            { $lookup: { from: 'users', localField: '_id.bidder', foreignField: '_id', as: 'bidderInfo' } },
            { $lookup: { from: 'auctions', localField: '_id.auction', foreignField: '_id', as: 'auctionInfo' } },
            { $unwind: '$bidderInfo' },
            { $unwind: '$auctionInfo' },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0, // Exclude the _id field
                    bidID: "$highestBid.bidID",
                    bidAmount: "$highestBid.bidAmount",
                    bidDate: "$highestBid.bidDate",
                    fullName: "$bidderInfo.fullName",
                    bidder: "$bidderInfo._id",
                    auctionID: "$auctionInfo._id",
                    auction: "$auctionInfo.title",
                    endDate: "$auctionInfo.endDate"
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    status: {
                        $cond: [
                            {
                                $and: [
                                    { $eq: ["$bidder", "$_id.bidder"] }, // User is highest bidder
                                    { $gt: ["$endDate", new Date()] } // Auction has not ended
                                ]
                            },
                            "You are the highest bidder",
                            {
                                $cond: [
                                    {
                                        $and: [
                                            { $ne: ["$bidder", "$_id.bidder"] }, // User is outbid
                                            { $gt: ["$endDate", new Date()] } // Auction has not ended
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "You have been outbid",
                                    {
                                        $cond: [
                                            { $eq: ["$bidder", "$_id.bidder"] }, // User is highest bidder
                                            "You won the auction",
                                            "You lost the auction" // Auction ended, and user is not the highest bidder
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            // Sort the result by bidder
            {
                $sort: {
                    userID: 1 // Sort by bidder in ascending order
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Would be great if you can share the sample data in JSON.

Comment: It might take lot of space here, so I thought to display in table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$setWindowFields` and `$switch`:

1. `$group` by `bidderID` and `auctionID`
2. `$lookup` to check if the auction is over (that is all the data we need)
3. `$setWindowFields` to get the highest bid per auction
4. `$set` to format the data
5. `$project` to calculate the `status`
6. `$sort`

```
db.bids.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: {bidder: "$bidderID", auction: "$auctionID"},
      myHighestBid: {$max: "$bidAmount"}
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "auctions",
      localField: "_id.auction",
      foreignField: "auctionID",
      as: "isEnded",
      pipeline: [{$project: {isEnded: {$lt: ["$endDate", "$$NOW"]}}}]
  }},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$_id.auction",
      sortBy: {myHighestBid: -1},
      output: {maxBidAmount: {
            $max: "$myHighestBid", 
            window: {documents: [ "unbounded", "current"]}}
      }
  }},
  {$set: {isEnded: {$first: "$isEnded.isEnded"}}},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      userID: "$_id.bidder",
      auctionID: "$_id.auction",
      maxBidAmount: "$myHighestBid",
      status: {$switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {$and: [{$eq: ["$myHighestBid", "$maxBidAmount"]},
                            "$isEnded"]},
              then: "You won the auction"
            },
            {
              case: {$and: [{$eq: ["$myHighestBid", "$maxBidAmount"]},
                            {$not: "$isEnded"}]},
              then: "You are the highest bidder"
            },
            {
              case: {$and: [{$lt: ["$myHighestBid", "$maxBidAmount"]},
                            "$isEnded"]},
              then: "You lost the auction"
            }
          ],
          default: "You have been outbid"
      }}
  }},
  {$sort: {userID: 1, auctionID: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oulpoWpWABO)

Comment: Thanks, much man. This works perfectly :)